# How the relationship between overviews and zoom level is determined

Tags: qgis, gdal, mapping, gdaladdo, map-overviews

I am trying to understand the relationship between overviews and zoom levels. For example, using gdaladdo I can create overviews at [2,4,8,16] or at just [16]. From my understanding, this means the size is being divided by those values to downsample.

In the latter, does it mean immediately when I am one zoom level higher than the zoom level that uses the source data, it will become 16x less pixels? And consequently for the first example ([2,4,8,16]) it will be 2x less, than 4x less and so on, not reaching 16x less until 4 zoom levels up?

Is this application dependent on whats reading the GeoTIFF or is it the same everywhere? My question is particularly for QGIS.